# Can one Electron app detect another and possibly message it?

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application, multiplatform, electron-forge

I'd like to make two separate Electron apps interact with each other, in different levels, depending on what's possible:

1. Have one app detect that the other app is installed;
2. Have one app fetch some information from the other.

In other words, when apps A and B are both installed in the same system, one app would be able to offer the user some options, when it knows that the other app is also installed. If possible, one app would be also able to fetch some data from the other app, e.g. importing user preferences.

Would anything like this be possible at all, with the current Electron API?

Comment: Regarding preferences, you can try to search a settings file on filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is to create an application-specific PID file, then look for it from the other app. Thanks to Vlad for pointing in the filesystem-based solution direction.